# What does “alias” mean with respect to the `Sync` trait?

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust, trying to figure out the `std::marker::Sync` trait. The documentation for `Sync` starts with the following (version 1.1), emphasis mine:

> Types that can be safely shared between threads when **aliased**.
>
> The precise definition is: a type `T` is `Sync` if `&T` is thread-safe. In other words, there is no possibility of data races when passing `&T` references between threads.
>
> As one would expect, primitive types like `u8` and `f64` are all `Sync`, and so are simple aggregate types containing them (like tuples, structs and enums). …

This makes zero sense to me, starting with the first sentence. I thought aliasing has to do with statements such as:

```
type Name = String;
```

What does this have to do with synchronization? Perhaps the term “alias” is overloaded here, and I'm missing the second meaning, but I can't find anywhere in the documentation referring to a second kind of aliasing.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A value is said to be *aliased* if there is more than one alias to it. An alias is just a name.

In this code:

```
let s1: String = "hello".into();
let s2: &String = &s1;
```

`s1` and `s2` are aliases of the same `String` value; therefore, the `String` is aliased.

Comment: Perhaps the first sentence of the documentation should read “when *their values are* aliased.” However, given your answer, I don't understand the third paragraph. Why are primitive types such as `u8` and `f64` synchronized merely by taking a reference to them? That doesn't seem right, so again I must be having trouble with the vocabulary here.

Comment: "a type `T` is `Sync` if `&T` is thread-safe". Note that this talks about *immutable* references. However, Rust allows interior mutability with `UnsafeCell`, on which `Cell` and `RefCell` are built. Types that contain cells, such as `Rc<T>` are not thread-safe by default, since multiple threads can race to read from or write to the contents of the cell.